# How can I use Jquery to slidedown elements that were hidden before adding to DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

I thought this was fairly simple. But, it's turning out to not be. I am working with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("button#submitComment").click(function () {

            // Get the div containg the comment list
            var commentList = $("#comments");

            // Get the ID of the last comment displayed so server 
            // can query recent non-displayed comments
            var lastId = $(".comment h4").last().attr("id");

            // Get data to post to server
            var commentData = "EntryId=" + $("input#EntryID").val()
                              + "&Comment=" + $("textarea#Comment").val()
                              + "&LastId=" + lastId;

            $.post(
                "/find/Comments/Comments",
                commentData,
                function (data) {
                    alert(data); // confirm server response

                    newComments = $(data).hide(); // hide elements so they can be animated after adding them to the DOM

                    commentList.append(newComments); // add to DOM

                    $(".comment").each(function () {
                        $(this).slideDown("fast") // animate
                    });

                    $("#Comment").attr("value", ""); // clear comment form
                }
            );

        });
    });

</script>
```

This script posts the comment to the server. the server responds with the markup form the posted comment, AND any comments posted since the user posted the page.

When the server returns markup for a single comment it works great. when the server responds with more than one comment then firefox blows a gasket. I get this JavaScript error:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0[nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:3437/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js :: anonymous :: line 130"  data: no]

That error is coming fom jQuery core, and I'm not sure exactly what's triggering it. I do know that if I remove the `.hide()` and the `.slideDown()` and just append the markup, then it works without a hitch. But I want fancy slideDown animations :-)

Any suggestions?

### Edit

Here's an example of the server's response:

```
<div class="comment" style="background:#eee; border:1px solid gray; padding:10px 10px 0 10px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <h4 id="94">Admin commented on Thursday, December 23, 2010 10:21 AM</h4>
    <p>
    asd
    </p>
</div>

<div class="comment" style="background:#eee; border:1px solid gray; padding:10px 10px 0 10px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <h4 id="105">Owner commented on Thursday, December 23, 2010 10:27 AM</h4>
    <p>
    asd
    </p>
</div>

<div class="comment" style="background:#eee; border:1px solid gray; padding:10px 10px 0 10px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <h4 id="106">Admin commented on Thursday, December 23, 2010 10:27 AM</h4>
    <p>
    asd
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: When you receive multiple comments they are probably comming in as an array of json objects.  Perhaps you need to treat the result set differently depending on whether you get one answer or multiple.  The service you are calling should also always return an array.  When there is only one item that array will have a single element.  That way you can treat the response the same no matter what.  Otherwise there should be two separate calls to the server, one to return a single comment, the other to return multiple.  I believe your problem is here: newComments = $(data).hide();

Comment: The server is just returning a string with html in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah,  Instead of doing $(data).hide() do

```
$(data).find('.comment').hide()
```

Or
    $(data).find('.comment').attr('style','display:none')

Of course the second one would overwrite your style attribute. You could wrap the whole thing in a span or div also.

Comment: Thanks... that got me on the right path. I ended up using: `newComments.filter(".comment").css('display', 'none');`. That did the trick. It's interesting the `.hide()` wouldn't work in this situation in firefox.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll have to look into the guts of jquery to figure this one out. Not sure what hide would do differently. Generally I tend to attach elements to the DOM before performing any operation on them like hide. So, this is likely something related to how detached elements behave.

Comment: I betcha it's because .hide() caches the original state of the element for .show().

Comment: From jquery.com: The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Answer (score 0):

This led me on the right path. My problem was caused by my array containing non-jquery objects in it. When I printed it to console, I got something like

```
[jquery-div, <TextNode textContent=" ">, jquery-div]
```

When I changed my ".hide()" to ".filter("div").hide()" it fixed the error.